# split paragraph into sentences in R

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I am using strsplit function to do this.

I have found many regexes for this purpose:

```
(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s
```

First of all I am getting error when I simply use it in R:

```
sl <- unlist(strsplit(txt1,"(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s"))
```

Error: '\w' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?

And also when I try to test it in
[regex tester](https://regex101.com)

it does not solve my problem
my paragraph is:

```
As of Feb. 9, the Ministry of Agriculture, Fisheries and Food
said that 9,998 cattle have been destroyed after being diagnosed
with BSE. The government has paid $6.1 million in compensation, and is
budgeting $16 million for 1990.
```

And I want 2 sentences

```
As of Feb. 9, the Ministry of Agriculture, Fisheries and Food
said that 9,998 cattle have been destroyed after being diagnosed
with BSE.
The government has paid $6.1 million in compensation, and is
budgeting $16 million for 1990.
```

but the above regex divides it in 3 sentences:

```
As of Feb.
9, the Ministry of Agriculture, Fisheries and Food said that 9,998 cattle have been destroyed after being diagnosed
with BSE.
The government has paid $6.1 million in compensation, and is
budgeting $16 million for 1990.
```

Comment: First, you need a double backslash `\\\` for the escape characters (One for R quotes and the other for regex).  Second, you could write your expression to find periods followed by a space and then capital letters or non-numbers.  Both would work in your example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get what you're trying to do with the two negative lookbehinds (`(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)`). You really just need the positive lookbehind you've got to search for periods and question marks before `(?<=\\.|\\?)` (maybe add exclamation points?), the space character `\\s`, and then add a positive lookahead for capital letters: `(?=[A-Z])`.

And yes, in R you need to escape everything with two backslashes (`\\`), and if you're using lookaheads or lookbehinds in `strsplit`, you need to specify `perl = TRUE`.

All told, what you really need is

```
 strsplit(txt1, "(?<=\\.|\\?)\\s(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)
```

which gives you

```
[[1]]
[1] "As of Feb. 9, the Ministry of Agriculture, Fisheries and Food said that 9,998 cattle have been destroyed after being diagnosed with BSE."
[2] "The government has paid $6.1 million in compensation, and is budgeting $16 million for 1990."
```

Comment: It is correct for this case but how to handle abbreviations in general.
For example below case
"Because of the disease, the U.S. Department of Agriculture's
Animal and Plant Health Inspection Service banned imports of
cattle, embryos and bull semen from Great Britain in July, said
Margaret Webb, a USDA spokeswoman in Washington."

This gives me two scentences:

"Because of the disease the U.S."
"Department of Agricultures Animal and Plant Health Inspection Service banned imports of cattle embryos and bull semen from Great Britain in July said Margaret Webb a USDA spokeswoman in Washington."

Comment: Yeah. The problem is that abbreviations in English are really non-standard ("U.S.", "etc.", "Dept."). There's really no way to use regex to tell the difference between "I live in the U.S. It is a country." and "I work for the U.S. Department of Education."; we can only tell the difference because we understand the content. The only way to deal with that sort of thing is to get into NLP, or at least use a parser built upon it.

Comment: So, there is no solution to this using regular expression??

Comment: Nope. With NLP, it's `library(NLP); library(openNLP);
an <- annotate(s, Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator());
lapply(an, function(x){substr(s, x$start, x$end)})`, which did handle a couple example abbreviations I threw at it well. What's happening is considerably more opaque, though.